# ASP.Net Core web-farm with distributed session handling in Redis

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, redis

I'm trying to create a web-farm with multiple docker containers all running the same ASP.NET Core  3.1 app. Hence, I need to manage a distributed session and my idea was to use Redis to do that.

According to [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-distribute-data-protection-keys-with-an-asp-net-core-web-app-8b2b5d52851b) I added the following statements to my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redis_connection_string);
services.AddDataProtection()
  .PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys")
  .SetApplicationName("seminarmanager");

services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(o =>
{
  o.Configuration = redis_connection_string;
  o.InstanceName = "seminarmanager";
});
```

Of course, I added two packages from Nuget to my app:

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis`
- `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis`

Unfortunately, distributed session handling does not work and I get a bunch of errors like the following:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {9b51134a-a57a-4129-9441-72859a985ab0} was not found in the key ring.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedText, ILogger logger)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware: Warning: Error unprotecting the session cookie.

In Redis the key "DataProtection-Keys" was created but has not value.

How can I successfully configure distributed session/key management with Redis?

Best regards...

Answer (score 1):

I actually found an answer by myself. I had to delete all existing localhost cookies from my browser. After that, everything worked.